# Check if the last digit in a 4 digit number is a 1

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Is there a way to check if the last digit of a 4-digit (or any digit) number is a 1?

I am trying to make something that checks if the first and last digit of a number are both 1.  Suppose our number is 1581.  To check if the first digit is 1 is trivial.  I can go..

if number - 2000 < 0 AND number - 999 > 0, then the first digit is always one.

Is there a test similar to above to check if the last digit is 1?

EDIT: Just to add more context to the question, we want to find an automated way to check if the number starts and ends with a 1.

Comment: What do you mean?  If you have the number, you can just look at the last digit.  If you want something that sounds fancier, just take the remainder on division by $10$.

Comment: This is part of an authentication license key that will be installed in our cloud to monitor for our applications.  After decoding our provided license key, the 1st and last digit should always be 1.  There will be thousands of customers and the key validation engine is a basic calculator that can only do floating point operations such as add, subtract, multiply, and divide

Comment: Does it have a MOD command?  Somthing like MOD(1481,10) =1

Comment: @RuiNian Why don't you just cast it to a string and verify directly?

Comment: Or FLOOR or INT that gives the integer part, then $1481-10×FLOOR(1481/10)=1$

Comment: @Empy2 Thanks a lot for your help! I just implemented your algorithm and tested it extensively. it works really well!  Feel free to provide that as an answer!

Comment: @PierreCarre Thanks for the suggestion, I'm not sure exactly how to do that in this really elementary engine that we're stuck working with :(

Comment: So what is the point of your license key? Why use a 4-digit number to represent a 2-digit number?

Comment: Hahaha the license key has a bunch of different things in it that might be a little too confusing to explain here!

Comment: "HaHaHa" doesn't suggest good security. However, that's all down to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has MOD then something like $$MOD(1481,10)=1$$.
If it has FLOOR or INT to give the integer part, then $$1481-10×FLOOR(1481/10)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

The following translates easily into most programming languages:

$$1000 \le x < 2000 \land x \mathrel{\mbox{mod}} 10 = 1$$

[And if you can, do tell us why you want to do this?]